# How to use Ribbon Buttons to execute code?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, ribbon

So far I have managed to create a ribbon with several buttons by following [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/013102/ribbon-control-in-wpf-4-5/).

Now I want to make the buttons actually do stuff! I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4339980/6302131) which shows how to execute already existing method. However if I do: Command="myCustomClass.myCustomMethod" and use

```
Class myCustomClass
    Public Sub myCustomMethod()
        'do stuff
    End Sub
End Class
```

I get the error `myCustomClass is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project`.

I also noticed this [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7249093/6302131) from the same post. After converting the code to VB.NET:

```
Public Class MyCommand
    Implements ICommand
    Public Sub Execute(parameter As Object) Implements ICommand.Execute
        Dim hello As String = TryCast(parameter, String)
        MsgBox(hello)
    End Sub

    Public Function CanExecute(parameter As Object) As Boolean Implements ICommand.CanExecute
        Return True
    End Function

    Public Event CanExecuteChanged As EventHandler Implements ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
End Class
```

and adding the references to the `<Window x:Class="MainWindow" ...` element:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyCommand x:Key="mycmd"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

I get the following error: `The name 'MyCommand' does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:RibbonSample"`.

I'm at a complete loss as to what I need to do to implement these buttons. Would it be possible to get any full ribbon samples using the same framework, with which I can learn from? I assume the solution to this should be really simple.

Comment: Rebuild your project, and make sure that the namespace matches.

Comment: @SLaks Yep! That did it! I'm still kind of confused as to why, but glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuild your project.

The WPF designer loads classes from your project's compiled assembly (so that it can actually execute your code).

If you add a new class, it will give you errors until you rebuild your project so the assembly includes that class.